# Reference code in other projects in Node.js using Visual Studio

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js, I am trying to setup an infrastructure where I would have a project making up a common layer on which other projects would build upon. I am using visual studio 2015. I am used to this IDE.

[The structure should look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grv1y.png)

[This is the structure I currently have in visual studio 2010 when using MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI8cU.png)

Comment: Both of the images are the same

Comment: Thanks Alex, I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are thinking of is a method in which you reference projects to create a layered infrastructure ?

If thats the situation, you are missing the part where NodeJS is just Javascript, not C# where your project compiles to DLLs you can reference.

You can make your NodeJS projects communicate via GET/POST requests, or share Javascript files.

Either way remember Javascript doesn't get compiled.

Comment: Would it make sense to have some sort of blank web application or Web API on a single project. Once this is running, my project and any future projects would call this API.

Answer (score 0):

You can get almost this by using Verdaccio, its almost the same you want but the references are done by external way, not inside Visual Studio, Verdaccio is a "lightweight private npm proxy registry", something like your own private npm registry where you can publish and import your own packages.
Cant found an extension to automate this but can be done with npm commands.

https://verdaccio.org/

Comment: Generally, links to a tool or library [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, and some sample code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605/584192). If the tool or library is not free-to-use, please also mention this in your answer.